# Woocommerce show comments by defaut

Tags: php, woocommerce

I created a product with a description. If I open the product page now the **description tab is shown before the comments/reviews tab**.

*How can I change that the comments/reviews tab is shown first?*

Thank you for your help,
Philipp

Comment: This depends on your theme, you will need to look in your theme file that is responsible to display the product and modify its code to suit your needs

Comment: Hello Moe! I use Sydney. Where can I find the code there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/#section-3) you can re-order tabs with the `woocommerce_product_tabs` filter :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_reorder_tabs', 98 );
function woo_reorder_tabs( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 5;           // Reviews first
    $tabs['description']['priority'] = 10;          // Description second
    $tabs['additional_information']['priority'] = 15;   // Additional information third

    return $tabs;
}
```

add this code to your theme's `functions.php`